# Azure SQL: How to decide a time to launch automatic calculation to avoid a performance peek?

Tags: azure, performance, azure-sql-database

**Context:** The web application needs to **pre-calculate some information in advance** to be more responsive and giving a feeling to see "as if on-line data". We have the mechanism that says "that portion of data is obsolete and should be retrieved/calculated now". Anyway, there is some flexibility, and slightly obsolete data are acceptable. There already is a tool to determine what things to be calculated or retrieved again.

**The question:** In Azure SQL, is there any mean to detect when to automatically launch calculation of a portion of data so that it would not cause performance problems? Say, **is there any system view, stored procedure, or so to get some performance counters?**

I am aware of the "Query Performance Insight for Azure SQL Database" application. However, I need something that can be used from the SQL query.

I admit that the question is rather fuzzy. I have to start somehow -- learning about possibilities.

**Update:**

I have just found the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/monitoring-with-dmvs?view=azuresql

Anyway, any comment related to your experience is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

My Understanding is in Azure SQL, you can use Dynamic Management Views  to monitor and gather performance-related information .
As per  my knowledge **sys.dm_exec_query_stats** could heIp and I  have tried this at my end and could help you monitor and gather performance-related information.

For example I have created a table. with below schema.

```
CREATE TABLE PerformanceMetrics (
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    MetricName NVARCHAR(50),
    MetricValue FLOAT,
    Timestamp DATETIME
);
```

[image]

As part of Dynamic Management View I executed **sys.dm_exec_query_stats** to monitor and gather performance-related information for few query opreations.

- Insert into Table:I have insert 25 records
- Select Query
- Update Statement to change the Coulmn name Metric to MetricName
- update statement to metricValue*2
- Updated Timestamp Format to ('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')

[image]

Results for the transformations
[image]

Now Using the **sys.dm_exec_query_stats** I am be able to fetch Top 10 highest total worker time, along with their execution count, SQL statement, total elapsed time, and creation time.

Here is the Query to perform On Azure SQl:

```
SELECT TOP 10
    qs.execution_count AS ExecutionCount,
    SUBSTRING(st.text, (qs.statement_start_offset / 2) + 1, (
        (CASE qs.statement_end_offset
            WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(st.text)
            ELSE qs.statement_end_offset END - qs.statement_start_offset
        ) / 2) + 1
    ) AS SQLStatement,
    qs.total_worker_time AS TotalWorkerTime,
    qs.total_elapsed_time AS TotalElapsedTime,
    qs.creation_time AS CreationTime
FROM
    sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs
CROSS APPLY
    sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) st
ORDER BY
    qs.total_worker_time DESC
```

;

[image]

**Result for sys.dm_exec_query_stats:**
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, DileeprajnarayanThumula. I know performance of my queries. I would like to get the information (statistics) of performance peaks by others. The other users and tasks are more important as the activity is the part of their ERP system. I want to find the "quiet time" to launch my procedures when the users are not in a hurry.

Comment: @SPT: ... or to up-vote if the comment is related, but does not solve the problem. So, I did. ;)